# php-ncurses cannot recognize the already installed php-common

Tags: php

I am trying to update my php version from 5.1.6 to 5.3.10 at Centos 5.4

I am trying to install the following rpm(i cannot yum or anything like that).

```
rpm -ivh php-ncurses-5.2.12-1.i386.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:     
php-common = 5.2.12-1 is needed by php-ncurses-5.2.12-1.i386
```

but i have install the php-common-5.3.10-1.el5.i386.rpm.

i have tried also other versions of ncurses for el5 but the same error occured

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not CentOS user (Archlinux here), but the general rule of updating `php` on Linux system is - you must have same version of `php` and plugins/extensions to make it work.

Afaik you are trying to update `php` to version 5.3.3, (and yet you've just install `php-common` in 5.3.10), staying with `php-ncurses` 5.2.12. I don't think that's going to work on any system. As you can see `php-ncurses-5.2.12` needs `php-common` in specific version (5.2.12 as well).

I'm almost sure that you should find backports of `php-ncurses` and `php-common` in 5.3.X version (same version for all the packages!) and then install it all together. If it's for some reason not possible, and if I were you I would probably remove `php-ncurses`, install `php-5.3.X` with `php-common-5.3.X` , then download and compile `php-ncurses` from source [[1]](https://pecl.php.net/package/ncurses/1.0.2) (there is another version naming scheme though).

I know nothing about machine you are working on, but if it's production machine you should probably do some tests on mirror machine/system first to make sure you will not break anything.

Comment: First thanks for the answer.

Second i am sorry for the typo but i am trying to update to version 5.3.10...i have edit at my first post.

so i have done what you have propose install a php-5.3.10 and a php-common-5.3.10.......the thing with the source i cannot get it or find how to install or even downloaded.

Comment: Well... compiling extension from source is really tedious work. Good luck thou.
Good starting point will be [php doc](http://php.net/ncurses), but you will probably need to dive in for few hours.

Comment: Maybe before compiling you should try [this one](http://pjwelsh.blogspot.com/2010/12/linux-rhelcentos-55-php-53-upgrade-made.html). Be carefull! It's 3rd party repo.

Comment: Well i have done it and fix it from the source i have find an rpm with pecl-ncurses 1.0.1 and that was it.....thanks for the help.

Comment: These are great news! I'm glad I helped.
Please, up-vote and mark as solved, if you think I've deserve it.

Comment: well some times the only thing you need is somebody to trigger your mind....thanks